# c# peer to peer programming (preferably decentralized)

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I'm writing an app to is to for sharing content. You have a list of "peers". You select a number of them and you can start sharing content (text and binary data).  On the local area network, if you enter the ip address of the other guys, then communication can go through.

I have a few questions

1. Is there some pattern to writing these kind of chatlike application that  enables discovery of who is online and who is not (both local and on the internet)? I know it can be done with a centralized server that all connects to but how about decentralized especially when you are on the LAN.
2. When connecting to online clients, they mostly do not have IP addresses but are rather behind firewall and stuff and obviously the ip address is not that of the machine and some ports will be blocked. What is the way around this?

PS: 
I've read a lot of stackoverflow pages on the matter. Some say it is possible, others say it is not. Now really sure which one to take. Some even had information about c# bit torrent clients and servers. I'm very open to suggestions as long as I can do it in .net. 
(c#, f#, vb are all ok)

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

regards

Comment: 1. Typically each instance would announce itself. You could try to find other instances but you'd need to know their IP address and port first. It can be done without a central server but you then need a list of common peers, one of which would have to be always on (on a rotational basis, not necessarily the same peer).

Comment: 2. If the port is blocked there is nothing you can do. That peer has to be the one to port forward and open the port. For security reasons one should never be able to do this from outside - or if they can, using some decent quality secure mechanism for doing so. Beyond that you seem to be asking "is it possible" (yes, subject to the restrictions noted) rather than "how do I do it" (not enough information).

Comment: So what do I do in the instances where either the clients are local but have dynamic ip addresses or when the clients are not on the same lan but typically across the internet. In this instance, their ip addresses may not be known.

Comment: If you can't broadcast (eg Internet) and you don't know their addresses in advance then it's impossible to know where they are unless they have advertised their address somewhere. You either need a known central location where those addresses can be found, or - as I said earlier - a decentralised set of known, common peers.

Answer (score 1):

Discovery means one end point must be able to find the other end points. On LAN it is doable if broadcast (UDP) is allowed on networking layer. A typical scenario is that an SNMP manager broadcasts an SNMP GET message, and see how many SNMP agents in the same network respond. This is decentralized, as there is no central registration spot where a list of all end points is stored.

However, going beyond LAN means there is no easy way like broadcasting to find other end points. Then a centralized solution is needed.

So please further summarize the scenarios for your applications in all layers (application, networking and so on) to see if a decentralized solution is available. Also when you read others' conclusions somewhere, you should also pay attention to the special scenarios he/she referred to. Those conclusions may be only valid to those scenarios.

Comment: I get it that from the internet, you definitely need a central server. In case I have some website (http://registration.mydomain.com) which the clients can access if using the internet, what do I need to get them talking without without the central server?

Comment: Once all clients register themselves on the central server with their IP addresses and opened ports, such information can be shared among them. Then each of them can initialize a direct connection to another (of course you need to work around NAT carefully).

Comment: Ok. So if I'm following, the client connects to the central server and their ips and ports are captured. If that is done, they can get information about the idea. My confusion is that the ip address may not be the direct ip address of the machine. Can you elaborate on the NATting part?

Comment: It is called hole punching, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_hole_punching. If you implement such mechanism inside your apps, then they can somehow get rid of the limitation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a central server (registration.mydomain.com) then one solution is as follows:
1. Peers connect to the central server with an "I'm here, here are my details" message.
2. Server records IP address and port of peer.
3. Peers request list of other peers from the server.
4. Peers connect directly to other peers using the supplied list.

Each peer should send updates to the server to indicate whether they are still there - or the server could try to connect to each peer on occasion (not always possible with all web servers) to determine the information itself.

Each peer should also periodically ask the server for more peers, in case any have connected or disconnected, though the latter would probably be noticeable in your socket anyway unless you're broadcasting.

Comment: That should work in the general sense. However, most of the time, the peers may not have IP addresses of their own but rather that of the router that they are using to connect to the internet. In this case, all peers behind the same router will appear to have the same Ip address. How will this be addressed?

Comment: You're kind of into "new question" territory. However, no matter where something connects from, there will be a port number. Use that in association with the IP address.